# Three hexadecimal digits can be used to represent 12 binary bits. Why is this sentence true?

Tags: binary

I've been looking at conversions from binary to hexadecimal. It says

> Three hexadecimal digits can be used to represent 12 binary bits.

Could someone please explain why that is? There wasn't any explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do some Math:

With 1 Hexadecimal digit you can show 16 different values.(0,1,2,...8,9,A,B,..,.E,F)

With 1 bit you can show 2 different values. (0,1)

3 Hexadecimal => : 16*16*16 = 2*2*2*2 * 2*2*2*2 * 2*2*2*2 variations possible

same as you can have with 12 Bits => 2*2*2*2 * 2*2*2*2 * 2*2*2*2

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I was originally trying to multiply 16*3, But's I'm supposed to do 16^3 instead. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Each hex digit represents 4 bits  (0-15 aka `0000` to `1111`) so three give 12.

qed.